# referencing columns of 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Following schema:

```
archivebox (id, mediatype_id)
mediatype (id, name)
archivebox_records (id, archiveboxId, recordId)
picture (id,name)
print (id,name)
```

recordId should be referenced whether to pictureId or printId. How is it possible to solve this problem? I work with mysql.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's always best to be explicit in your designs. This would involve creating two tables `archive_pictures` and `archive_prints` with foreign key relationships to the respective tables.

If you *really* don't want to go down that route, try adding some sort of record indicator to the `archive_records` table, eg

```
ALTER TABLE `archive_records` ADD `record_type` ENUM('picture', 'print') NOT NULL;
```

You can then create queries based on this indicator

```
SELECT p.name FROM picture p
INNER JOIN archive_records ar
    ON ar.record_type = 'picture' AND p.id = ar.recordId
```

Comment: If splitting the `archivebox_records` table was not an option, I would rather split the `recordId` column into `pictureId` & `printId` instead of adding a `record_type`. That way I could define foreign keys referencing the respective tables.

Comment: I will split records-table into arcivebox_prints und arcivebox_films. The indicator like record_type would not solve the problem of forein key referencies from recordId to printId and filmId..

Answer (score 1):

Another *clean* solution is to merge `picture` and `print` into

```
medium( id, name, type)
```

where `type` can be `"print"` or `"picture"` or when the datamodel grows the foreign key referencing a table containing the allowed values.

Comment: It would not work as both tables have many specific properties, it is not good to put them together into one table (eg medium)

Comment: Well, in that case, I'd recommend what Andriy M suggested yesterday.